# Display CollectionView Cell Image In New ViewController - Image not loading - Firebase / Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to link images in a collectionview cell to when tapped, opens a new view controller with that image. This is the code I have so far however the image does not load on to the new view controller. This is my code for my collectionview. I would appreciate help or advice a lot! Thank you

CollectionView

```
   func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
             
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
        
        vc?.name = images[indexPath.row].url

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        
        switch mMode {
        
        case .view:
            imageCollection.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            let image = images[indexPath.item]
        case .select:
            dictionarySelectedIndexPath[indexPath] = true
        }
    }
```

DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    var name = ""
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/Images/\("name")")
        
        loadDB()

    }
    
    func loadDB() {
        
       dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            var newImages = [UserImages]()
            
            for UserImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                let UserImagesObject = UserImages(snapshot: UserImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(UserImagesObject)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.img.image = UIImage(named: self.name)
            }    
        })  
    }
}
```

Comment: change sequence in view did load. call this funcation ```loadDB()``` after ```dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/Images/\(name)") ```

Comment: Hi Raja, thank you for that advice and it does work in terms of compiling it! I appreciate your input a lot, thank you.

Comment: There are a few code issues 1) `let image = images[indexPath.item` doesn't do anything with `image`; what's supposed to happen there? 2) `viewDidLoad` creates a reference to load an image using the var `name` but name is an empty string. 3) You don't need `DispatchQueue.main.async {` in Firebase closures as UI calls are on the main thread, networking is on a background thread. Also, for general coding practice, please start variable names with a lower case. Upper case are reserved for Class and Struct names; so `UserImagesSnapshot` should be `userImagesSnapshot`. It makes code more readable.